# Добавление атрибутов с помощью рефлексии

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Можно ли добавить атрибут для класса с помощью рефлексии?

Test.cs:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public void TestMessage()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Test message!");
    }
}
```

ITest.cs:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void TestMessage();
}
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[SomeAttribute]
public class Test : ITest
{
    public void TestMessage()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Test message!");
    }
}
```

Comment: [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24413055/2881286) из английского вопроса

Comment: Но зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: Действительно, проще завести свой словарь атрибутов и добавлять  атрибуты в него. Ну или вы некорректно описали задачу, может вам нужен PostSharp?

Comment: Да, спасибо всем за помощь.